# How to use Nginx RTMP to stream complex routes

Tags: video, nginx, video-streaming, rtmp

The nginx rtmp module states it does not do patterned routes.

I have a library of 10's thousands videos in directories like:
 /media/orl-stream/400000/410000/410900/test.mp4

I would like a single RTMP application as below to handle all the videos in the subdirectories on /media.

I have tested on WOWZA and once there is a / in the name the video does not play. I have  also tried double //.

```
    application mp4_vbit_low {

        live on;
         exec_pull /usr/bin/avconv  -re  -i /media/orl-stream/$name.mp4
           -c:v libx264 -g 50 -preset fast  -b:v 2048k -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -acodec copy
           -f flv rtmp://172.26.170.11:1935/mp4_vbit_low/$name;
      }
```

Here is a log entry that did  not play:

`... PLAY "mp4_vbit_low" "videos/test" "" - 595 436      "http://www.wowza.com  /resources/3.5.0/examples/LiveVideoStreaming/FlashRTMPPlayer/player.html" "WIN 16,0,0,305" (4m 51s)`

/media/orl-stream/videos/test.mp4 does exist.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Found it!

Add double // in the output stream   ".../mp4_vbit_low//$name;"

```
exec_pull /usr/bin/avconv  -re  -i /media/orl-stream/$name.mp4
           -c:v libx264 -g 50 -preset fast  -b:v 2048k -c:a libfdk_aac -ar 44100 -acodec copy
           -f flv rtmp://172.26.170.11:1935/mp4_vbit_low//$name;
```